# In Webstorm, how do you hide a module's non-exported variables/functions in auto-completion?

Tags: autocomplete, module, typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

If you take a look at the image below, notice how even the variables/functions accessible only in the scope of the module are exposed in the **auto-completion** menu when used outside the module.

This also occurs when using the given module in other **TypeScript** files of the same project, they appear the same as below.

Odd thing is, the icons seems to reflect their "private vs. public" status correctly, I'm not sure why the private ones aren't hidden altogether.

Is there a known option to hide these in WebStorm?

*(alternatively, PHPStorm? I think they have very similar settings / options)*

[image]

Comment: i'd suggest creating a support ticket. It's a bug in WebStorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. I have created issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18106

Bug was created for variables visibility. Visibility check for functions work fine for the latest [WebStorm 11 EAP](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/webstorm-11-eap-142-4723/)

Comment: Just an update on this - I've received a reply from JetBrains saying it's now fixed in WebStorm 11. All I can do for now is wait to upgrade I guess. (link to their tweet: https://twitter.com/WebStormIDE/status/642270003513962496)